# unable to scale down Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Cassandra/Kubernetes cluster on GCP

```
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$ kubectl get statefulsets --all-namespaces                                                                                                        
NAMESPACE       NAME                       READY   AGE
cass-operator   cluster1-dc1-default-sts   3/3     2d9h
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$ kubectl get all -n cass-operator                                                                                                                 
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/cass-operator-5f8cdf99fc-9c5g4   1/1     Running   0          2d9h
pod/cluster1-dc1-default-sts-0       2/2     Running   0          2d9h
pod/cluster1-dc1-default-sts-1       2/2     Running   0          2d9h
pod/cluster1-dc1-default-sts-2       2/2     Running   0          2d9h

NAME                                          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)             AGE
service/cass-operator-metrics                 ClusterIP      10.51.243.147   <none>          8383/TCP,8686/TCP   2d9h
service/cassandra-loadbalancer                LoadBalancer   10.51.240.24    34.91.214.233   9042:30870/TCP      37h
service/cassandradatacenter-webhook-service   ClusterIP      10.51.243.86    <none>          443/TCP             2d9h
service/cluster1-dc1-all-pods-service         ClusterIP      None            <none>          <none>              2d9h
service/cluster1-dc1-service                  ClusterIP      None            <none>          9042/TCP,8080/TCP   2d9h
service/cluster1-seed-service                 ClusterIP      None            <none>          <none>              2d9h

NAME                            READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/cass-operator   1/1     1            1           2d9h

NAME                                       DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/cass-operator-5f8cdf99fc   1         1         1       2d9h

NAME                                        READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/cluster1-dc1-default-sts   3/3     2d9h
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$
```

I want to scale it down from 3 nodes to 2 nodes. I am tried running the following commands but both failed.

```
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$ kubectl scale statefulsets cluster1-dc1-default-sts --replicas=2
Error from server (NotFound): statefulsets.apps "cluster1-dc1-default-sts" not found
```

What is the right command to scale down cluster?

Comment: execute command in `cass-operator` namespace

Comment: `kubectl scale sts statefulset.apps/cluster1-dc1-default-sts --replicas=2 -n cass-operator`

Comment: it should also work without `statefulset.apps/` prefix

Comment: thanks. It works with -n but without specifying statefulset.apps. If I specify statefulsets/.app, I get error - error: there is no need to specify a resource type as a separate argument when passing arguments in resource/name form (e.g. 'kubectl get resource/<resource_name>' instead of 'kubectl get resource resource/<resource_name>'

Comment: happy to accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute command in correct namespace using `-n` parameter (`-n cass-operator` in your case)

```
kubectl scale statefulsets cluster1-dc1-default-sts --replicas=2 -n cass-operator
```

You can also change namespace for all subsequent commands using

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=cass-operator
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `-n` parameter to specify correct `namespace` where the `statfulset` is deployed. Without the `namespace` it's trying to delete from `default` namespace where the `statfulset` `cluster1-dc1-default-sts` does not exist.

```
kubectl scale statefulsets cluster1-dc1-default-sts --replicas=2 -n cass-operator
```